I have a question for a post on the Bitcoin site. Can I post a long FAQ Q&A on bitcoin and cryptocurrency?
Well, as the title says, am I able to post a long FAQ Q&A on bitcoin and cryptocurrency? I feel like it could help some people. 
Would it be considered off-topic?
Example:

Why does X happen?

Well, x happens because.... 

As far as I understand you, you're trying to do something like Andrew Chow did here in this answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/54457/5406
If that's the case and the content is relevant to our topic, please feel free to post your FAQ as an answer to a relevant question or ask your own question to answer it with your FAQ. Kindly, when you do, post a link where to find it, because I'm curious what you've got for us.
Thank you. :)

Alright, I will brainstorm some stuff for it. Thanks so much!

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73803/bitcoin-frequently-asked-questions-with-answers here it is, it is not very long though.

Ah… I see. I thought your questions were all about one topic. I'm afraid, I agree with Pieter, it's a bit of an ill fit how you've posted it. I think however, that it would fit decently as an answer to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/5406, what do you think?

Alright, @murch I will post it.
